# How to get nested json object/value in scala

Tags: json, scala

I have Elasticsearch Search response that is a deeply nested Json file and I am stuck as to how to get a particular value from it.  Please am new to Scala and programming in general and I have searched online and could not see any answer that explained it well.
This is the Json file and the value I want to get out is "getSum":"value"

```
Search_response: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse = {
  "took" : 32,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myIndex",
      "_type" : "myType",
      "_id" : "4151202002020",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"pint":[{"printer":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Lam":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Kam":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Jas":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"tiv":[{ourc""s:"wrer","sourceType":"rsd","Vag":"agaatttt363336"}],"timeLineSource:[{"LA":"DGAT","GATA":"JAS","timeline":9.111694,"GA":"SFWF2525252552552525"}
    }, {
       "_index" : "myIndex",
      "_type" : "myType",
      "_id" : "4151202002020",
      "_score" : 1.0,
       "_source":{"pint":[{"printer":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Lam":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Kam":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Jas":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"tiv":[{ourc""s:"wrer","sourceType":"rsd","Vag":"agaatttt363336"}],"timeLineSource:[{"LA":"DGAT","GATA":"JAS","timeline":9.111694,"GA":"SFWF2525252552552525"}
    }, {
        "_index" : "myIndex",
      "_type" : "myType",
      "_id" : "4151202002020",
      "_score" : 1.0,
       "_source":{"pint":[{"printer":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Lam":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Kam":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"},{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"Jas":[{"sourceName":"3636636","sourceType":"Bin","Star":0.0,"Fun":"gatayay"}],"tiv":[{ourc""s:"wrer","sourceType":"rsd","Vag":"agaatttt363336"}],"timeLineSource:[{"LA":"DGAT","GATA":"JAS","timeline":9.111694,"GA":"SFWF2525252552552525"}
    }, {
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "DAEY" : {
      "doc_count" : 59,
      "histogram" : {
        "buckets" : [ {
          "key_as_string" : "1978-02-22T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1503360000000,
          "doc_count" : 59,
          "nestedValue" : {
            "doc_count" : 177,
            "getSum" : {
              "value" : 768.0690221786499
            }
          },
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I tried
val getResult: String = searchResult.toString.stripMargin
val getValue = JsonParser.parse(getResult).asInstanceOf[JObject].values("aggregations").toString

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using type-safe config. Please find the required maven and sbt dependency below -

Maven Dependecy -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Sbt Dependency -

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
```

Afterwards, you can get the value of sum with below code -

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(getResult)
config.getConfigList("aggregations.DAEY.buckets").get(0).getString("nestedValue .getSum.value")
```

Checkout API doc for library from this [link](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/README.md#overview)

Comment: Thanks but I've added the dependency but doesn't seem to have access to "config"

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to initialise config. Please take a look at modified answer.

Comment: @PeterJones Found this very helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally used

```
val getResult: String = searchResult.toString.stripMargin   
val getValue = JsonParser.parse(getResult).asInstanceOf[JObject].values("aggregations").toString
val valueToDouble = getValue.split(" ").last.dropRight(13).toDouble
```